# WCF Service concurrency issues and timeouts

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have a WCF service which receives a message from one application and send a notification to the other connected client applications.

In my first test scenario one client application is sending a big amount of messages to the service each second, while another two applications are receiving these messages from the service. In this test my service works perfect.

However, if I add another client application sending messages (2 applications sending messages to the service) applications crash and throw Timeout exceptions (SendTimeOut most of the times).

The amount of messages per second in the second test is lower than in the first test because I use Thread.Sleep() between requests, so I think the problem is about the number of applications sending request more than the number of requests, but I am not sure.

Do you know why are these issues happening?

My service and client applications are coded as following:

Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICacheCommunicatorServiceCallback), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface ICacheCommunicatorService
{
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsOneWay = true)]
    void Connect(string appName, string machineName);

    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = true, IsOneWay = true)]
    void DisconnectClient(ICacheCommunicatorServiceCallback callback);

    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginSendNotification(Notification notification, AsyncCallback callback, object state);
    void EndSendNotification(IAsyncResult result);
}
```

Requesting method code:

```
public IAsyncResult BeginSendNotification(Notification notification, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        try
        {
            ICacheCommunicatorServiceCallback current = CurrentCallback;

            ClientInfo sender = clients[current];

            foreach (ICacheCommunicatorServiceCallback client in clients.Keys)
            {                   
                if (client != current)
                {                       
                    if (((ICommunicationObject)client).State == CommunicationState.Opened)
                    {
                        client.ReceiveNotification(notification);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DisconnectClient(client);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log(e);
        }
        return new CompletedAsyncResult();
    }

    public void EndSendNotification(IAsyncResult asyncResult) { }
```

Service configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="CacheCommunicator.CacheCommunicatorService">
    <endpoint address="tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBindingConfiguration"
      name="TcpEndpoint" contract="CacheCommunicator.ICacheCommunicatorService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="MexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8733/CacheCommunicator/" />
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/CacheCommunicator/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpBindingConfiguration"
             closeTimeout="00:00:05"
             maxBufferSize="1048576"
             maxBufferPoolSize="1048576"
             maxConnections="10"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576"
             openTimeout="00:00:05"
             receiveTimeout="01:00:00"
             sendTimeout="01:00:00"
             transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1048576" maxBytesPerRead="1048576" maxStringContentLength="1048576"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="false" inactivityTimeout="01:00:00"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Client requests calls:

```
internal void SendNotification(Notification notification)
    {
        if (!isConnected()) this.Connect();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            proxy.SendNotification(notification);    
        }).HandleExceptions();
    }
```

Client applications configuration:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="TcpEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false"/>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out setting throttling settings explicitly for server WCF service:

```xml
<serviceBehaviors>
   <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
       <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200"
                          maxConcurrentInstances ="100" 
                          maxConcurrentSessions ="100"/>
   </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

BTW, Which ConcurrrencyMode / InstanceMode is used for WCF service?

Suggested for read:

- [WCF Instancing, Concurrency, and Throttling – Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-1.aspx)
- [WCF Instancing, Concurrency, and Throttling – Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickrain/archive/2009/06/17/wcf-instancing-concurrency-and-throttling-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The WCF service uses InstanceMode.Single and ConcurrencyMode.Multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling .Close() on your client proxy after each call. You can make multiple calls thru one instance of a proxy, but always .Close() when you are done with the client calls.